# Can I implement an interface while instantiating an anonymous class?

Tags: java, instantiation, anonymous-class

Suppose I have an abstract class `FactorizedDialog`. It looks like this (please note that this is just some dummy example)

```
public abstract class FactorizedDialog extends Dialog {

  public abstract void myMethod();
}
```

Now I can do something like this:

```
FactorizedDialog dialog = new FactorizedDialog() {

            @Override
            public void myMethod() {
                // implementation here
            }
}
```

As you may have guessed I extend Dialog (which is in fact an abstract class) only to add a method to it so I can override it when I create an anonymous class. Is it possible to implement an interface in **java** while I instantiate Dialog instead of using my derived abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you specify the superclass of an anonymous inner class you can *either* specify a normal class to extend *or* an interface, but not both. The syntax shown in [section 15.9 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9) simply doesn't allow for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the below where `Dialog` is an interface, then yes it can be done.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog() {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
    }
}
```

Of course then the declaration of `myMethod` should go into the `Dialog` interface.

Comment: As I mentioned both are abstract classes.

Comment: @edem Yes, I noticed that after posting my answer.